# receive json object in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC. My HTML code is:

```
<form action="/Electronics/Temp1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="files" id="fileNames" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And i am appending data in input field as:

```
$("input[id*='fileNames']").val(JSON.stringify(fileList));
```

The data in `fileList` is:
[image]

To receive this data I created a class as below:

```
public class FileName
    {
        public string serverFileName;
        public string fileName;
        public string fileId;
    }
```

Now in Controller i am receiving as:

```
public ActionResult Temp1()
    {
        FileName[] fileName = Request["files"]; //How to convert ?

        return Json(new { Message = "Ok" });
    }
```

but i am getting error on first line of `Temp1`. How can I parse Json data to `FileName` .

Comment: Your question and contents don't match with each other

Comment: I updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Deserialize json string to an abject with [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library. 
for example:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
```

Comment: I downloaded Json.Net by the command `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`. Now how to use it? `JsonConvert` is not in intellisence

Comment: @IrfanWattoo use this    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert or using Newtonsoft.Json;

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC internal model binders can deserialize the JSON string for you. You can just set the expected models as parameters in the action/method and see the magic.

```
public ActionResult Temp1(FileName[] files)
{
    // work with files

    return Json(new { Message = "Ok" });
}
```

By the way, it is better to use properties in the model class - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields

```
public class FileName
{
    public string ServerFileName { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string FileId { get; set; }
}
```